# Configuring subdomain in Laragon

Tags: apache, ssl, laragon

I'm using Laragon on Windows 10, and I want to create a subdomain for a new project,
The current structure is:

```
https://management.test
https://management.test/includes
https://management.test/client
```

I want to access the client folder using this URL:
https://client.management.test
But I don't want to have https://includes.management.test

I want the configuration to be only on the client folder.

I've tried playing with the Apache sites-enabled file but didn't get the result,
Can anyone share a working example with me or a simple solution to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Any ideas on how I could setup wildcard subdomains in laragon?.

Comment: Any ideas on how I could setup wildcard subdomains in laragon?.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured this out.
This "manual" solution worked for me

- I edited drivers\etc\hosts and added my subdomain like

```
127.0.0.1    sub.project.test
```

- Enable mod_vhost_alias.so in laragon\bin\apache[version]\conf\httpd.conf
- Create a new file like {laragon folder}\etc\apache2\sites-enabled\sub.project.test.conf"
- Add the following code in the file you just created

```py
define ROOT "C:/laragon/htdocs/project/sub/"
define SITE "sub.project.test"

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot ${ROOT}
    ServerName ${SITE}
    ServerAlias *.${SITE}
    <Directory "${ROOT}">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "${ROOT}"
    ServerName ${SITE}
    ServerAlias *.${SITE}
    <Directory "${ROOT}">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.key
 
</VirtualHost>
```

Replace ROOT to the path to the subdomain folder

- Finally reload apache and visit the subdomain

References :

- https://forum.laragon.org/topic/1705/help-subdomain-laragon/3
- https://github.com/leokhoa/laragon/issues/90

Comment: In my case I had to exit from laragon whole app to get this. Before that I was getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error!

Comment: I hope a way to do this easily is added to Laragon in future updates

Comment: cant we add 127.0.0.1    *.project.test

Comment: @AbhiBurk i haven't tried that. You can try an let me know if it works

Comment: na windows does not support the wildcard

Comment: Good to know. Thanks